# Problems with CRUD using Laravel and Vue.js

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I've recently start using vue with laravel.

I've build a blade view in a on going project and use a vue template on it, i can see everything normaly but, when the page loads i receive:
"[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as , as they will not be parsed."
when i try to save, i get 422 and 500 errors.

Also this will be a multi-page app.

I've already tryied giving the type for the script tag in the blade, change the script tag for section tag, both without success.
As for the save, i log console my data in the template and all the data was there, as i was expecting but, for some reason, this data is going with some error to the controller, honestly, i've been for two weeks trying to solve this, i rewrote my code a lot of times and still didn't figure.
Can someone please help me o rgive some ideias?

Follow the code:

That's the blade file:

```
@extends('portal.template')

@section('content')
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{ url('/portal-cambos') }}">Portal Cambos</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{ url('/portal-cambos/tecelagem') }}">Tecelagem</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Manuteção</li>
        <li class=" ml-auto">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" onclick="goBack()">
                <i class="fa fa-reply"></i> Voltar
            </button>
        </li>
    </ol>

    <div id="app">
        <index rotaadd="tecelagem/manutencao/"></index>
    </div>

    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
@endsection
```

The main vue component:

```
<template>
    <div class="tec-manut-pages">
        <PageTitle main="Manutenções Tecelagem" />
        <div class="tec-manut-pages-tabs">
            <b-card no-body>
                <b-tabs pills card>
                    <b-tab title="Máquinas com Manutençao Próxima" active>
                        Manutenções Próximas
                    </b-tab>
                    <b-tab title="Tipos de Manutenção">
                        <manutencao-tipos
                                rotaadd="manutencao/tipos/"
                                rotasalvar="manutencao/tipos/salvar/"/>
                    </b-tab>
                    <b-tab title="Cadastro de Manutenções">
                        Cadastro de Manutenções
                    </b-tab>
                    <b-tab title="Relatórios">
                        Relatórios
                    </b-tab>
                </b-tabs>
            </b-card>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import PageTitle from '../../PageTitle'
    import ManutencaoTipos from "./manutencaoTipos";

    export default {
        name: "index",
        components: {PageTitle, ManutencaoTipos}
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

The second vue component:

```
<template>
    <div class="tec-manu-tipo" id="tec-manu-tipo">
        <b-form>
            <b-row>
                <b-col md="4" sm="12">
                    <b-form-group label="Tipo: " label-for="tipo">
                        <b-form-select id="tipo" v-model="type.tipo" :options="options" :readonly="mode === 'remove'"></b-form-select>
                    </b-form-group>
                </b-col>

                <b-col md="4" sm="12">
                    <b-form-group label="Manutenção: " label-for="manutencao">
                        <b-form-input id="manutencao" v-model="type.manutencao" placeholder="Informe o nome da manutenção..." :readonly="mode === 'remove'" />
                    </b-form-group>
                </b-col>

                <b-col md="4" sm="12">
                    <b-form-group label="Período: " label-for="periodo">
                        <b-form-input id="manutencao" v-model="type.periodo" placeholder="Informe o período da manutenção em dias..." :readonly="mode === 'remove'" />
                    </b-form-group>
                </b-col>
            </b-row>

            <b-row>
                <b-col xs="12">
                    <b-button variant="primary" v-if="mode === 'save'" @click="save">Salvar</b-button>
                    <b-button variant="danger" v-if="mode === 'remove'" @click="remove">Excluir</b-button>
                    <b-button class="ml-2" @click="reset">Cancelar</b-button>
                </b-col>
            </b-row>
        </b-form>
        <hr>
        <b-table hover striped>
            <template slot="actions">
                <b-button variant="warning" class="mr-2">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                </b-button>

                <b-button variant="danger">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                </b-button>
            </template>
        </b-table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios'

    export default {
        name: "manutencaoTipos",
        props:['rotaadd', 'rotasalvar', 'nomes'],
        data() {
            return {
                mode: 'save',
                type: {
                    tipo: '',
                    manutencao: '',
                    periodo: ''
                },
                tipos: [],
                options: [
                    {value: null, text: 'Escolha o Tipo...'},
                    {value: '0', text: 'Corretiva'},
                    {value: '1', text: 'Preventiva'},
                    {value: '2', text: 'Limpeza'}
                ]
            }
        },
        methods:{
            reset(){
                this.mode = 'save'
                this.type = {}
                this.loadTypes()
            },
            save(){
                //console.log(this.tipo)
                axios.post(this.rotasalvar, this.type)
                    .then((res) => {
                        window.location.href ='http://127.0.0.1:8000/portal-cambos/tecelagem/manutencao';
                    }).catch((err) => {
                    console.error(err)
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

app.js:

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');
window.BootstrapVue = require('bootstrap-vue');
window.VueRouter=require('vue-router').default;
window.VueAxios=require('vue-axios').default;
window.Axios = require('axios').default;

Vue.use(BootstrapVue);

//let AppIndex= require('./components/tecelagem/manutencao/index.vue');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the body of the page. From here, you may begin adding components to
 * the application, or feel free to tweak this setup for your needs.
 */

Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue').default);
Vue.component('add-produtos', require('./components/tecelagem/add-produtos.vue').default);
//Vue.component('rform', require('./components/tecelagem/RForm.vue').default);
Vue.component('index', require('./components/tecelagem/manutencao/index.vue').default);
Vue.component('tipos', require('./components/tecelagem/manutencao/manutencaoTipos.vue').default);

/*const index = Vue.component('index', require('./components/tecelagem/manutencao/index.vue'));

Vue.use(VueRouter,VueAxios, axios);

const routes = [
    {
        name: 'Index',
        path: '/',
        component: index
    }
];

const router = new VueRouter({ mode: 'history', routes: routes});

new Vue(
    Vue.util.extend(
        { router },
        AppIndex
    )
).$mount('#app');*/

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

Function to save in the controller:

```
public function saveType(Request $request){
        try{
            \DB::beginTransaction();
            $input = $request->all();

            foreach($input as $entrada){

                $tipo = new TecManutencaoTipo();
                $tipo->tipo = $entrada->tipo;
                $tipo->manutencao = $entrada->manutencao;
                $tipo->periodo = $entrada->periodo;
                $tipo->save();
            }

            \DB::commit();

            return response()->json('salvo', 200);

        } catch (\Exception $e){
            \DB::rollback();
            return response()->json($e.'erro', 422);
        }
    }
```

The Routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'manutencao'], function () {
            Route::get('', ['as' => 'tecelagem.manutencao', 'uses' => 'TecelagemManutencaoController@index']);

            Route::group(['prefix' => 'tipos'], function () {
                //Route::get('', ['as' => 'tecelagem.manutencao.tipos', 'uses' => 'TecelagemManutencaoController@']);
                Route::post('salvar', ['as' => 'tecelagem.manutencao.tipos.salvar', 'uses' => 'TecelagemManutencaoController@saveType']);
            });
        });
```

As i said before, i'm facing problems the complete this save operation, a think that if i can do so, i'll be able to make the next ones.

I apreciate any help and if needed, i can put some more information.

Thank you all.

Comment: A 500 error is fairly generic, and you should have more information found in your Laravel or PHP/web server log. You're returning a 422 error yourself, but you aren't doing anything with the exception. Try adding a `Log::info('TecManutencaoTipo failed: '.$e->getMessage());` inside of your catch block, then check the Laravel logs in `storage/logs` to see what message is being returned.

Comment: Can you share the code on any vcs  like github to clone the code and help you fix errors!

Comment: Hi @aynber, thanks for been helping me, i'm getting "[2019-07-16 16:13:52] laravel.INFO: TecManutencaoTipo failed: Trying to get property 'tipo' of non-object"
What i don't understand is why is not getting this property.

Comment: @mohamedhassan, thanks for replying to, unfortunately, i can't, this is a piece of a bigger project all build in laravel by a collegue of my here, i'm introducing vue now, plus the project itself is to big already, i'm truly sorry and thanks again. If there's any more code that you think necessary i can edit the original question.

Comment: Can you share screen shots of errors ?
May put component:{index} in new vue({
el:"#app", components:{index}});
will help

Comment: `$entrada` is not an object. Try `Log::info($entrada);` at the start of your while loop to find out what it is. It's most likely an array, so the proper format would be `$entrada['tipo'];`, but double-check the log first.

Comment: @aynber, i get "[2019-07-16 16:29:39] laravel.INFO: 0", this confirm your suspects?

Comment: No, it now looks like it's an integer instead of an array. Try `Log::info($input);` before the loop, what do you have?

Comment: @mohamedhassan, i've tryied and get this error: "app.js:81480 Uncaught ReferenceError: index is not defined
    at Object../resources/assets/js/app.js (app.js:81480)"

Comment: @aynber, it returns the array:"[2019-07-16 16:37:07] laravel.INFO: array (
  'tipo' => '0',
  'manutencao' => 'qwert',
  'periodo' => '1',
)"
But there's a lot of lines before that in the log.
Can i use $input directly instead of using the loop?

Comment: Yes, it looks like you can. Remove the loop and use `$input['tipo']` instead.

Comment: @aynber, it works, greatly, how can i give you the deserved points? Thak you very much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `Log::info($input);`, it was determined that a single array was being sent instead of an array of objects. So you would need to remove the loop, and access the data via the array keys instead:

```
public function saveType(Request $request){
    try{
        \DB::beginTransaction();
        $input = $request->all();

        $tipo = new TecManutencaoTipo();
        $tipo->tipo = $input['tipo'];
        $tipo->manutencao = $input['manutencao'];
        $tipo->periodo = $input['periodo'];
        $tipo->save();

        \DB::commit();

        return response()->json('salvo', 200);

    } catch (\Exception $e){
        \DB::rollback();
        Log::info("Unable to save TecManutencaoTipo, ".$e->getMessage());
        return response()->json($e.'erro', 422);
    }
}
```